# 'Unable to Access Page' error when clicking 'Save & New Task' from public calendar event

Tags: public-calendar

A user reported that they were unable to click the 'Save & New Task' button when on a public calendar. I was able to find a Known Issue [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XAjAAM) but it has No Fix and no way to mark that I'm effected by the issue. Does this mean there is no way to fix the issue and it's just a known defect?

Comment: That's fun. Open a support case and I bet it will at least take a few months for them to close it.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. You can only set `I'm affected` on issues that are not in a final (i.e. closed) state. Final states are `No Fix` and `Fixed`. All other states (`In Review`, `Scheduled` and `Release in Progress`) do have the `I'm affected` button.

That you might see people that have reported that they were affected by the issue even when the issue is set to `No Fix` is because they hit the button when the issue was still in a non-closed state, i.e. before the issue was set to `No Fix`.